# How to get selected radio button value from visibile HTML area?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have following HTML with two `ULs`.

```
<a href="javascript:;" id="detail_buttons">Click</a>

<ul class="plan none">
    <li>
        <p>One month</p>
        <label for="2" class="label_radio">
            <input type="radio" value="40" id="2" data-name="Be Bold" name="be_bold">
        </label> <strong>40 ₪</strong>

    </li>
    <li>
        <p>Three months</p>
        <label for="3" class="label_radio">
            <input type="radio" value="70" id="3" data-name="Be Bold" name="be_bold" checked="checked">
        </label> <strong>70 ₪</strong>

    </li>
    <li>
        <p>Six months</p>
        <label for="4" class="label_radio">
            <input type="radio" value="100" id="4" data-name="Be Bold" name="be_bold">
        </label> <strong>100 ₪</strong>

    </li>
</ul>
<hr />
<ul class="plan">
    <li>
        <p>One month</p>
        <label for="2" class="label_radio">
            <input type="radio" value="40" id="2" data-name="Be Bold" name="be_bold_two">
        </label> <strong>40 ₪</strong>

    </li>
    <li>
        <p>Three months</p>
        <label for="3" class="label_radio">
            <input type="radio" value="70" id="3" data-name="Be Bold" name="be_bold_two">
        </label> <strong>70 ₪</strong>

    </li>
    <li>
        <p>Six months</p>
        <label for="4" class="label_radio">
            <input type="radio" value="100" id="4" data-name="Be Bold" name="be_bold_two">
        </label> <strong>100 ₪</strong>
    </li>
</ul>
```

First UL is with `display: none` and have one radio button is selected by default and Second UL is without selected.

Now I want get selected radio button value from visible `UL`.

Here is my jQuery Code:

```
$("#detail_buttons").click(function () {
    if ($(".plan input[type='radio']:checked").val() != undefined) {
        alert($(".plan input[type='radio']:checked").val());
    }
});
```

My JSFiddle: [Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/jj879trx/)

Any Idea?

Thanks.

Comment: couldn't understand can you please explore more about your problem.?

Answer (score 0):

Use this way:

```
$(".plan:visible").find("input:radio:checked").val();
```

**Snippet**

```js
$("#detail_buttons").click(function () {
  alert($(".plan:visible").find("input:radio:checked").val());
  return false;
});
```

```css
.none {display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="detail_buttons">Check Value</a>
<ul class="plan none">
  <li>
    <p>One month</p>
    <label for="2" class="label_radio">
      <input type="radio" value="40" id="2" data-name="Be Bold" name="be_bold">
    </label> <strong>40 ₪</strong>

  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Three months</p>
    <label for="3" class="label_radio">
      <input type="radio" value="70" id="3" data-name="Be Bold" name="be_bold" checked="checked">
    </label> <strong>70 ₪</strong>

  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Six months</p>
    <label for="4" class="label_radio">
      <input type="radio" value="100" id="4" data-name="Be Bold" name="be_bold">
    </label> <strong>100 ₪</strong>

  </li>
</ul>
<hr />
<ul class="plan">
  <li>
    <p>One month</p>
    <label for="2" class="label_radio">
      <input type="radio" value="40" id="2" data-name="Be Bold" name="be_bold_two">
    </label> <strong>40 ₪</strong>

  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Three months</p>
    <label for="3" class="label_radio">
      <input type="radio" value="70" id="3" data-name="Be Bold" name="be_bold_two">
    </label> <strong>70 ₪</strong>

  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Six months</p>
    <label for="4" class="label_radio">
      <input type="radio" value="100" id="4" data-name="Be Bold" name="be_bold_two">
    </label> <strong>100 ₪</strong>
  </li>
</ul>
```